# Как добавить в visual studio 2015 вывод дебажной информации в самом редакторе?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка, ide

Как добавить показ дебажной информации в Visual Studio 2015 непосредственно в редакторе кода а не в отдельной панели. Хотелось бы как например а Intelij Idea или в chrome:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы именуете "дебажной информацией"? Вывод текущих значений переменных? Ну, так это все работает, по крайней мере при работе с C++ и C#, про питон не знаю.

Comment: Нет, этого не было до обновления `ReSharper` . У меня старый `ReSharper` стоял.

Comment: @Alex это есть в чистой студии из коробки. Скорее всего ваш старый решарпер просто отключил это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ReSharper 2017.3.1 как раз появился такой функционал как у вас на скрине. Ну и всегда вы можете навести мышку на переменную в режиме отладки и увидеть значение.

Comment: Спасибо, после обновления `ReSharper` появилось, а наводить не всегда удобно я бы сказал.

Comment: @Alex так у вас вопрос был скорее не о студии, а о решарпере. У студии показ значений переменных работает безо всякого доп.инструментария.